# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars, why?

Tags: python, typeerror

I want a graphic of phase in function of frequency, but if I run my code, the output gives me a type error of 
f = np.arange(1,1000000)
faseverschuiving_functie(mt.atan(2*np.pi*f*R*C)* (180/(np.pi))). I have no idea why.

I tried already to change arange in to linspace but I have still the same problem.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import math as mt

R = 1000
C = 470*pow(10,-9)
f = np.arange(1,1000000)

kantelfrequentie = 1/(2*np.pi*R*C)
print("De kantelfrequentie is ",kantelfrequentie,"Hz")

Faseverschuiving = mt.atan(2*np.pi*R*C*kantelfrequentie)
print("De faseverschuiving bedraagt",Faseverschuiving,"rad")
#Omzetten radialen in graden
Faseverschuiving = Faseverschuiving * (180/(np.pi))
print("De faseverschuiving bedraagt",Faseverschuiving,"°")

faseverschuiving_functie = []

#Functie opstellen
faseverschuiving_functie(mt.atan(2*np.pi*f*R*C)* (180/(np.pi)))

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Plot de eerste grafiek
#Grootte van de figuur en de subplot bepalen 
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.subplot(111)
#Titel van de grafiek
plt.title("faseverschuiving = f(frequentie)")
#Grafiek plotten
plt.plot(f,faseverschuiving_functie,"r*-",label = "Faseverschuiving")
#Assen benoemen
plt.xlabel("f (Hz)")
plt.ylabel("φ (°)")
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
```

Normally the output for this code is a graphic, but de faseverschuiving_functie give me an type error, i have no idea why. The length of f (frequentie) and faseverschuiving_functie are the same.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `math.atan` expects a scalar value and somewhere inside it, it makes that assertion. If you try to call `math.atan([1,2])` for example, it will throw also a `TypeError`, whereas `2 * np.pi * f * R * C` yields an array.

There's also a problem with `faseverschuiving_functie`, which you define earlier in your code as `faseverschuiving_functie = []`. Calling `faseverschuiving_functie` will result in an error because `faseverschuiving_functie` is a list not a function.